# NextUI Select Component onChange option

Tags: reactjs, onchange, nextui

```
<Select
    label="Starting City"
    className='max-w-xs mx-auto shadow-lg'
    startContent={<LocationCityIcon/>}
    >
      {citiesArray.map ((city) => (
        <SelectItem key={city} value={city} onChange={() => handleStartingCityChange(city)}>{city}</SelectItem>

      ))}

    </Select>
```

I'm using NextUI's Select and SelectItem components.I'm simply trying to change a variable according to the string I select from an array. I have a handleStartingCityChange function called whenever I shall change the SelectItem's value. For now, I'm simply console logging things on this function yet there is nothing appears. I'd really love to get some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://nextui.org/docs/components/select#controlled)
Event **onChange** is to be applied **on Select** which is main component, **not on SelectItem**.
*There is an onChange example provided right below the Controlled example, mentioned in above link*

**Please  try the code below :**

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import { Select, SelectItem } from "@nextui-org/react";

const CitySelect = () => {

    let options = [

        { label: "City 1", value: "city1" },
        { label: "City 2", value: "city2" },
        { label: "City 3", value: "city3" },
    ]

    const [SelectedCity, SetSelectedCity] = React.useState(new Set([options[0]['value']]));
    // SETTING DEFAULT CITY AS 1ST CITY

    const [Variable, SetVariable] = useState("-")
    // A  Variable THAT WILL CHANGE according to the SelectedCity



    const handleSelectionChange = (e) => {
        SetSelectedCity(new Set([e.target.value]));
        console.log("Selected City", Array.from(SelectedCity));

        // YOU MAY NOTICE THAT SELECTION IS OLD, LAGGING BEHIND LATEST STATE
        // TO FIX THAT USE, useMemo 
        // Using Array.from() to make a array out of Set Data type
    };




    // WHENEVER SelectedCity CHANGES useMemo will be fired
    useMemo(() => {
        console.log("City Selection Changed : ", Array.from(SelectedCity));
        // Using Array.from() to make a array out of Set Data type
        console.log("Changing the variable :", Array.from(SelectedCity)[0].toUpperCase());
        SetVariable(Array.from(SelectedCity)[0].toUpperCase())
    }, [SelectedCity])


    return (
        <div>
            <h3>This Variable changes according to SelectedCity : {Variable}</h3>
            <Select
                items={options}
                selectedKeys={SelectedCity}
                // onSelectionChange={SetSelectedCity} // DIRECTLY CHANGES SELECTED VALUE

                onChange={handleSelectionChange}

                /*
                    when you use onSelectionChange dont use onChange & vice-a-versa, JUST ONE of them
                */


                defaultSelectedKeys={SelectedCity}
                // SETTING DEFAULT SELECTED KEY AS 1ST CITY
                label="Favorite City"
                placeholder="Select an City"

            >
                {
                    (options) => <SelectItem key={options.value} value={options.value}>
                        {/* LOOK HERE CLOSELY NO EVENTS APPLIED HERE*/}
                        {options.label}
                    </SelectItem>
                }
            </Select>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CitySelect
```